# Send message from WeChat mini-program to web-view

Tags: javascript, webview, wechat

I'm building WeChat Mini-Program that on one of it's pages has `web-view` control. For example:

**page.wxml**

```html
<web-view src="https://..." bindmessage="onWebViewMessage"></web-view>
```

**page.js**

```
const app = getApp();
Page({
    onWebViewMessage:function(e) {
         console.log(e);
    },
    onLoad:function() {
    }
});
```

In `web-view` an HTML page is loaded (index.html), that includes `jweixin-1.3.2.js` lib from WeChat, for connecting with WeChat API as well as connect to parent Mini-program. Page is empty, no DOM elements, just javascript that will execute when document is loaded.

It has it's javascript something like this:

**index.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    wx.miniProgram.postMessage({data:'test'});
});
```

I am able to post messages from this document to mini-program without issues. Also can send some mini-program navigation commands such as `wx.miniProgram.navigateTo({url:'path/to/page'});` so all seems fine. I can also get callback in Mini-program when `web-view` has completed loading.

**Question:**

How can I post message **from** Mini-program to web-view? For example, to pass a string or an Object to the web-view.

I have been googling for hours and can't seem to find anyone doing it, but I can't believe it's just one-way communication possible.

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Comment: Would be very helpful to understand why this question was down-voted, considering that online information about this topic is very limited. Knowing what was the issue with it would help me improve in my future questions.

Comment: not receive a message from the webpage.

Comment: @KamleshDelat correct, problem was how to send data from mini-program to webpage inside web-view, since there is no API to do that.

Comment: @Sunisa the actual problem is not getting message in the mini programme send by HTML using wx.miniProgram.postMessage

Comment: @KamleshDelat I think you misunderstood. Issue is how can I send message from mini program to web view in any moment. Multiple messages if needed, whenever required. Web view can send back message to mini program by wx.miniProgram.postMessage, but there is no API for the other way around. Hence my question.

Comment: wx.miniProgram.postMessage send message after webView unload or destroy it's not for real-time communications

Comment: @KamleshDelat what I am looking for is real-time communication from mini-program to web-view, not the other way around.

Comment: same thing I am also looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an effective way to pass data from mini-program to web-view content, and it seems at this moment in time, this is the only possible way to do it.

### Mini-program

#### 1. Base64 module

You will need to be able to convert normal String into Base64 string. Mini-program API has a method for converting byte array into base64 string, but that won't be usable for this purpose. So, create your own module that does that:

File: `lib/b64.js`

```
var string2base64 = function(str) {
    .... here put your js code for making b64 string ....
    return result;
};

module.exports = {
    string2base64
};
```

#### 2. Page with Web-View

In the page that has `web-view` control, prepare DOM element in `wxml` file like this:

File: `pages/xxx/index.wxml`

```html
<web-view src="{{webURL}}" bindload="onWebLoad" binderror="onWebError"></web-view>
```

Notice that `src` parameter is now bound to page's `webURL` property. Whenever page sets value to this property, will automatically be applied to the DOM elemenet.

In file `pages/xxx/index.js` you will need to add base64 module:

```
const b64 = require('../../lib/b64.js')
```

*note that require path may vary depending how you have setup your project*

and in page's `data` object, add `webURL` and `webBaseURL` properties, like this:

```
Page({
    data: {
        webURL:'',
        webBaseURL:'https://your/web/app/url',
        messageQueue:[],
        messageQueueSize:0,
        .... other page properties go here ....
    },
    ..... rest of your page code goes here .....
})
```

Notice that `webURL` is set to be empty. This means that when page loads, an empty string will be set to DOM object by default.

`webBaseURL` will explain just in a bit.

`messageQueue` is an Array that will store pending messages to be sent to web-view.
`messageQueueSize` is just Array length. Used for better performance, to avoid reading Array.length.

#### 3. Start Message Queue

In `onShow` callback of the page, set `webURL` and start interval that will read `messageQueue` Array every 250ms. You can change the way this is done if you dislike using intervals, this was just simplest way to do theory test.

```
onShow: function(){
    // This will start loading of the content in web-view
    this.setData({webURL: this.data.webBaseURL } );

    // Sends message from message queue to web-view
    let _this = this;
    setInterval(function(e) {
        if( _this.data.messageQueueSize < 1 ) return;
        _this.data.messageQueueSize --;
        let msg = _this.data.messageQueue.splice(0,1);
        _this.setData({webURL: _this.data.webBaseURL+"#"+msg});
    },250);
}
```

You can see that message is appended to web-view source (url) as a hash.

`webBaseURL` is used to generate final URL with hash, that is then send to web-view.

#### 4. Add a Message to the Queue

To create a message in message queue, just define following method in your page:

```
addMessageToQueue: function(obj) {
    obj.unique = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
    let msg = b64.string2base64(JSON.stringify(obj));
    this.data.messageQueue.push(msg);
    this.data.messageQueueSize++;
}
```

Whenever you call this method, just pass an Object with whatever properties you need it to have, and it will be converted into JSON string, then to base64 string, and finally appended to the message queue.

`unique` property is added to make generated base64 result always different even if the rest of object properties are the same - I just needed this for the purpose of my project. You can ignore it / remove it if you do not need it.

Since there's interval running and checking on the message queue, all messages added like this will be sent to web-view in the same order they were added to the queue.

Now there's only one thing left - to add hash change listening in the HTML page we have loaded into the web-view:

### HTML Web-app

#### 1. Listen to hash change

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function(e){
    let messageBase64 = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    let json = window.atob( messageBase64 );
    let data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log("Received data from mini-program:",data);
});
```

Tested on Xiaomi Mi8 Pro. I am yet to test on other devices sold in China.

Cheers!